# Joomla 3.x language file issues

Tags: xml, joomla3.0

I have a module with a language file which mostly works but I can't get it to work with type = "text"

The module xml file has

```
<field name="heading_text_activities" 
type="text" default="W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" 
description = "W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" 
label="W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" size="10" />
</fieldset>
```

the language file has

```
W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT="Enter heading text"
W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_HEADING_TEXT_ACTIVITIES="Heading Text Activities"
W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT="Enter heading text"
```

The trouble is the default shows in the text input box W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT and not the Enter heading text string.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong but the rest of the file work correctly just this one part refuses to work.

Any idea where I can look or a way to debug?

thanks

Comment: Seeing that you have been a member of Joomla Stack Exchange for 7 months, please post your Joomla questions there so that that community can grow and become a better resource for all.  When Irfan and Amit see that more Joomla questions are landing there, they will bring more of their expertise to that community on a more regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the language files to work you have to include it in the site language folder. That is done through module xml file adding a code this way

```
<languages folder="path/to/language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.mod_yourmodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_yourmodule.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

Also suppose your module name is mod_yourmodule and your language text is `W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT` then its better to prepend it with module name like `MOD_YOURMODULE_W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT`.

Also you can check this link for details https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files. It says in point number 2 that

```
All KEY's in the frontend shall include a prefix of the extension
```

For the language key to translate the default value you need to add

```
translate_default="true"
```

to the field option this way

```
   <field name="heading_text_activities" 
    type="text" default="W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" 
    description = "W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" 
    label="W4C_WEEKLY_ACTIVITIES_ENTER_HEADING_TEXT" 
    size="10" 
    translate_default="true" />
```

Comment: The language file work fine for all the page elements.  So  it's installed correctly.  It's only the default='xxx that won't work when I put in plain text it's  fine.  I wondered if default can't be set in the language file?

Comment: Ok I understood your point. I have edited the answer just check the end part you need to use translate_default="true" .

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your issue as described in [**Joomla docs**](https://docs.joomla.org/Debugging_a_translation).

> You activate language debugging via the Administration Back-end by
>   going into Global Configuration and clicking on the System tab. Find
>   the Debug Language field, change the value to “Yes” and save your
>   changes.

This way you can find whether the issue is in the translation file or in the file name. I hope this would help.